# apt install xfce4 also installs gnome

Tags: gnome, xfce, lightdm

I have a small server with Ubuntu server 20.04.2 LTS installed. I wanted to also have a desktop environment on it so I run:

`sudo apt install xfce4`

Then I chose LightDM during install.

After a reboot I noticed both XFCE4 and Gnome are installed because I logged in and noticed it was Gnome desktop...

It was a fresh installed Ubuntu server, I only installed cockpit and cockpit-machines on it.

Why is this happening and what did I do wrong?

Comment: Look in your your /var/log/apt/history.log for the list of what apt installed and when. If that does not answer your question, then post the log details in your question above.

Comment: XFCE relies on the GTK+ stack so parts are expected. You've not been specific as to what you're asking about.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xfce4 etc (inc. https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/desktop-base so do did you install recommends?)

Comment: Please have a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4/+bug/1841260 and if it applies; say it affects me & leave a comment saying so (and that you're using *focal* or 20.04).  If you do that, you'll be confirming the bug matters on a supported release (currently it's only seen as an issue on *disco* or a now EOL release).   (but noted by jphilips; #xubuntu-devel; https://askubuntu.com/users/375840/jay-philips)

Comment: Thanks guiverc! I have added a comment on the bug report, it's exactly the same problem as what I have.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is **not** the latest release (that is 20.10 or the 2020-October *groovy* release), however Thank you for providing the confirmation... I'll use your addition to re-open (remove 'incomplete' on that bug report).  Thank you for helping to make Ubuntu & Xubuntu better.